# Is there a good jquery plugin for masked/regex input?

Tags: jquery, maskedinput

My need is simple - I would like to let the user input currency values in a sane manner, meaning:

1. Pasting an integer yields an integer, i.e. pasting `12345` gives `12345` and not `123.45`
2. Pasting a fractional value yields the same value, i.e. pasting `1234.5` yields `1234.5` and not `123.45`. Pasting `1234.0` should yield either `1234` or `1234.0` or `1234.00` - any is valid, but I guess the middle one should be the easiest.
3. The fraction separator `.` must be explicit and optional. I.e. a user can type `12345` or the user can type `123.45`. The two inputs yield different values - see the first two items.
4. The input is not fixed size. I.e. both `123` and `1234` and `12345` and `12.3` are valid inputs.
5. Pasting bad input should be blocked. Preferably, by simple removal of the offending characters.
6. Typing bad input should be blocked as well. Which means any prefix of a valid input is expected to be valid as well. Therefore, typing/pasting `123.` is allowed.
7. As a bonus, the developer should be able to specify that the integer part be displayed with `,` dividing the thousands, millions, etc... I.e. `1234567.8` would be displayed as `1,234,567.8`

The regular expression for such input (omitting the comma thing) would be `/^[1-9]\d*(\.\d{0,2})?$/` (notice that `.` is allowed to be the last character).

Now, I have tried several jQuery plugins, which seem to be the most popular on the web. Unfortunately, neither one fits the bill:

- http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meiomask/

  Do not know how to enforce 1,2 and 3: http://jsfiddle.net/mark69_fnd/gKuaH/
- http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

  Do not know how to enforce 1,2,3 and 4. Pasting behaves strange. http://jsfiddle.net/mark69_fnd/jF86D/
- http://akzhan.github.com/jquery-keyfilter/

  Unsuitable for this particular task at all, since the regex seems to be applied on each character, rather than on the input as a whole: http://jsfiddle.net/mark69_fnd/uj9ZK/

Are my constraints so extraordinary? I do not think so. Can anyone suggest an alternative to the examined plugins that would satisfy all of the constraints?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

An implementation by Robin Herbots - https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask. Seems very interesting, looks like everything is supported except for the bonus. Still checking - http://jsfiddle.net/mark69_fnd/KW4qn/

**EDIT2**

Unfortunately, https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask has its own share of problems. For instance, it defines several useful input masks in the extension files, but I just cannot understand how it works (but I may simply be stupid). However, it seems to mess my styling too. A numeric field that is declared as center aligned by my css becomes right aligned. As much as I understand the reasoning, this is unacceptable. In short, no love.

Comment: Why not find a plugin you like and modify it to use your regex?

Comment: Why would I be kidding? What's so hard about swapping out a function?

Comment: This is not at all about swapping a function. I think you are wrong. But you can prove otherwise by trying it yourself and sharing the results.

Comment: I'll see what I can do. If you don't need any of the other masking features you can get away with a much smaller and simpler implementation.

Comment: Wow, less than half an hour between asking a question and answering it yourself. Why bother asking?

Comment: Because this is a process. I knew only about the first two plugins, the other one seemed marginal. As I wrote the question, I decided to check it as well.

Comment: Besides, that plugin seems to deserve more references than it currently has.

Comment: Just deleted my answer. The joy was premature.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the alignment like this.

```
$('#test').inputmask('decimal', { rightAlignNumerics: false });
```

;-)

Answer (score 0):

See this plnkr.

http://plnkr.co/edit/OE6PGTuCvQa380S7b8Zg?p=preview

It validates a regexp on each keypress via jquery.simulate

I don't know how to build the regexp for your needs but that mask tool and simulate are what you're after.